# How simple is Path.GetFileName?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

In C#.net if I were to write this method:

```
public static string returnFileNameOnly(string returnString)
{
    string val = returnString.Substring(returnString.LastIndexOf("/"));

    return val;
}
```

Would I have pretty much just rewritten Path.GetFileName? Or is there more to it than that? As far as I can tell, `Path.GetFileName(fileVariable.FileName)` and `fileVariable.FileName` return the same thing unless the user is using Internet Explorer (although I have only tried it on IE, Chrome, and Firefox).

Wasn't sure if that was all there was to that method or not, really.

----------------For Those Who Are Curious-----------------------

I ask because I have used something very similar to the method I wrote above on a site a long time ago, before I learned the `Path.GetFileName` method, and I wasn't sure if I should bother changing it or not.

Comment: It probably has a bit more error checking than that..  and possibly supports other directory separation characters depending on the environment.

Comment: I thought it might, I guess I should probably dig up some old dusty cshtml files, then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to mscrolib disasm, I can say that GetFileName is not so much more complicated then your implementation.
*GetFileName* do the following.

1. *GetFileName* checks if path contains invalid characteres (*System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars*).
2. After that it splits your path using *System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar*, *System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar* and *System.IO.Path.VolumeSeparatoChar*.
3. And only then returns filename.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Is this verified? (I'm really asking, I don't know if it is or not, that is, I don't know what mscrolib disasm is). Have any links to that?

Comment: Yeah, I watch mscorlib disasm right now! Here is it. You can see it yourself =)

Comment: Okay, great, thanks! A lot of helpful answers here, but, to be fair, yours is the most complete in regards to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

- Paths that don't have slashes in them at all.
- Paths that have backslashes but no regular slashes.
- Alternate systems that might someday run .NET with non-Windows filename conventions.

Comment: So I should probably just go back and fix it, in your opinion? I should be able to do this very easily, without breaking it (famous last words...).

Comment: I'm sure Mono implements it in a more platform-agnostic way.

Comment: It's probably fine as is. It's a good thing to make a note of on your next refactoring run, when you have unit tests in place to catch yourself. (See what I did there?)

Answer (score 4):

You could always go poke around (shared source | Rotor | Mono | Reflector | dotPeek):

```
public static string GetFileName(string path)
{
    if (path != null)
    {
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path);
        int length = path.Length;
        int num2 = length;
        while (--num2 >= 0)
        {
            char ch = path[num2];
            if (((ch == DirectorySeparatorChar) || 
                (ch == AltDirectorySeparatorChar)) || 
                (ch == VolumeSeparatorChar))
            {
                return path.Substring(num2 + 1, (length - num2) - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: You said, "You could always go poke around (shared source | Rotor | Mono | Reflector | dotPeek):"

I have no idea what that is...

Comment: @VoidKing Oh, apologies: Reflector and dotPeek are basically .NET decompilers. Rotor is the shared-source drop from Microsoft (the sorta-open-source parts of .NET) - and Mono is the cross-platform variant of the CLR.

Comment: Any link or advice on how to get started with that? Which one should I use for asp.net-webpages? Also, +1 for posting such useful methods I wasn't aware of... Are there any other "CheckInvalid...Chars" methods?

Comment: @VoidKing well, I'd start with either dotPeek (http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or ILSpy (http://ilspy.net/) - download, install, toss any old .NET assemblies you can find into them, see how they tick. :)

Answer (score 1):

The system method is probably more complex because you can have both / and \ as directory separators. But I would definitely say: **If it works, don't try to fix it!**

Since this system method seems to be simple and short, I would go for a c# decompiler to watch its internals.

Dis# - well known commercial one, trial version available: http://www.netdecompiler.com/

Jetbrains dotPeek - another famous one, free of charge: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Your answer leaves me as undecided as when I posted this question, LOL. The saying, "if it's not broken, don't fix it" is gooooood advice indeed, though :)

Comment: If you are really desperate to know it, then go and use a C# decompiler. It will clearly show you what exactly that method does and I bet it will be faster than asking here. ;-)

Comment: To my knowledge, I have never seen a C# decompiler. Where could I go to find such a thing?

Comment: Thank You! +1 for useful diagnostic information (which is very useful in the context of this question)!